# Is it possible to use a UPS or power inverter in place of a dying battery in a laptop?

Tags: laptop, battery, power, ups, asus-laptop

My battery is dying and I can’t buy the a new battery because its not available in my country (India). My battery model is [A41-X550E (ASUS)](http://www.uspartsdirect.com/asus-a41-x550e-44-wh-Li-ion-14-4-v-3070-mah-laptop-battery-p-191627.html?origin0=product-ads&gclid=CPK85InR3scCFc6PHwod2cILEg).

[image]

And it’s inside my laptop like this:

[image]

So that’s why I am planning to plug in the laptop AC adapter into the UPS and UPS to the wall. Is it safe to do so?

Or can I use a pure sine wave power inverter in place of the UPS?

Comment: Asus has no offices in India?

Comment: it has, but this laptop is imported. parts are not available, including the battery. checked all online sites already.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect a UPS up and it will work fine - it is, however, very inefficient.

I am unsure what you would be trying to achieve with a pure sinewave converter.  If you are trying to protect your device - and on an unsupported assumption your power quality is extremely bad - you can probably get a spike catcher a lot cheaper - certainly your laptop does not require a pure sinusoidal wave to work.

A quick google found a plethora of suitable batteries on EBAY - many shipping from China - so why not simply buy one from there ?

Comment: thanks.
i actually don't need battery. my laptop stays turned on most of the time. Plus I have bad experience with buying batteries online before.

May I ask.. what do you mean by inefficient?

Comment: Well, a UPS or sinewave convertor is going to consume power, an "online" UPS or Sinewave converter would, I imagine, consume inthe order of 20% of the power going to the laptop, and the laptop will then take that power and again waste some of it - especially if you have a battery in it.     Even crappy battery (including your old one even if it only holds charge for a couple of minutes) should do an adequate job of filtering out noise and spikes, negating the need for fancy conditioning equipment.

Comment: Another approach would be to import the battery from the USA - You may not be aware of places like "Via Box" [ there are a few of them ] which will allow you to ship to an address in the USA, and then forward it on to you.  Just be sure they will laptop batteries before using that kind of service.  Looking at UPS, it should be possible, but there may be delays.   Looks like you can't use USPS.

Comment: thanks.
i am aware of those services. but the real problem is, the customs department in our country. you can't rely on them. also, i bought a dell inspiron battery before, it lasted only 1 month. that was a bad experience.

i have my desktop ups. i was thinking of using it with my laptop.
i just need about ~20 minutes backup(i don't use laptop while travelling etc). can it be harmful to use it with the laptop?

it gives 20 minutes back up to the desktop. how much will it give to the laptop?

Comment: If you already have a UPS, use it, it certainly won't harm the laptop.   No one can tell you how much it will give the laptop without more details - How long did your (approx 3000mAH) laptop battery last, what kind of battery does the UPS have in it and what is its condition.    In any event if the battery in the UPS is in good condition it should last at least as long as a new laptop battery.  (Even a small UPS battey is 7000mAH at 12 volts)

Comment: my laptop's battery still gives me good back up(2-4.5 hours depending upon the usage). but i am asking this because asus denied to provide support(i still have warranty- long story) and my battery wear level is increasing rapidly, plus power problems.

the ups gives 20 minutes back up to the desktop. can you tell me how to check which kind of battery my ups uses? its model is numeric digital 600 ex.